# Why is it "weight was", and "thighs were"?

Tags: difference, past-tense

I'm just working on a website, to do with tracking body measurements, which measures weight, hips, thighs, biceps, chest and waist.

I've noticed when dealing with past data, I write weight/waist/chest as "Your weight/waist/chest was x", but all the other are written "Your thighs were x, your hips were x etc".

What's the reason for needing to use both were and was?

Comment: This seems like subject verb agreement.  Weight, waist and chest are singular. Thighs, arms, hips are plural.

Comment: For the same reason you say "one cat _is_" and "two cats _are_". I'm really confused about what your actual question is. Your question is written well, and you use singular and plural verb forms correctly, so I don't think _that_ is what is confusing you, but I don't know what _is_.

Comment: It actually was the plural that was confusing me. For some reason my head didn't recognize the words as single/plural, and that's what was confusing me about needing was and were.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a misunderstanding that was easily dealt with and isn't concerning anyone anymore.

Comment: The thighs aren't being measured individually, correct, but as a single circumference?

Comment: @TRomano Even if that's true, **thighs** is still plural. You could say *My thigh measurement was...* and that would be correct.

Comment: @Catija: I was trying to find out whether it was a measurement "at the thighs" i.e. "of the thighs (together, close-legged), or "of the thigh (assuming both are the same)".

Comment: @TRomano OH!  Gotcha. You actually need both measurements for different things.  In fitness, it's probably primarily the circumference of a single thigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Catija mentioned, it's really quite simple:

You have one weight, one chest, and one waist.
You have two thighs, two hips and two arms.

Conjugation of 'to be' says:

One object **was**
Multiple objects **were**

So your weight was, and your thighs were.